# Unable to use MapController without app crashing

Tags: android, android-maps, android-mapview

I have two MapActivities, and the one that uses the user's current location works great.  When I try to create the second MapActivity, which uses a hard coded lat / longitude it will crash when using MapController to animate to or set zoom.  My code is as follows:

```
package com.breckbus.app;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class Yellowroute extends MapActivity {
    MapController mControl;
    GeoPoint GeoP;
    MapView mapV;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.yellowroute);

        mapV = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.yellowmapView);

        mapV.displayZoomControls(true);
        mapV.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        double lat = 39.482547;
        double longi = -106.047699;

        GeoP = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (longi * 1E6));

        mControl.animateTo(GeoP);
        mControl.setZoom(13);

        mapV.invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;

    }

} //end of map.java
```

If I take out either mControl.animateTo(GeoP) or mControl.setZoom(13) the app will run fine.  But, if I leave either in, I get the following:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQjh1.jpg

I'm pulling my hair out...any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you give us the logcat error message

Answer (score 2):

Your controller is null, you need to add a line to instantiate it

```
mapV = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.yellowmapView);
mControl = mapV.getController(); // < You need to add this line
```

Comment: You sir, are a saint!  I'd give you an upvote but I do not yet have enough reputation.  Thanks again!